# meaning of distinct and how to use it in python(pymongo)

Tags: python, pymongo

I don't understand what is the meaning of distinct and how use of it. i have search for related answer but it seems like distinct is somehow related to list. really appreciate the help.

```
list_of_stocks = db.stocks.distinct("symbol")
```

Comment: none of that code is built-in python keywords. what package are you using? you'll need to include more context or information.

Comment: i'm using python 3.6

Comment: The version of python is irrelevant here: You're using some type of database, of which we have no idea, as you haven't given any information about it: no import statement, no database name... And as already stated: `distinct` isn't a python keyword. It's part of the (unnamed) database library you're using.

Comment: thanks, but we need to know what libraries, external packages you are using. i.e. what is `db`? what is `stocks`? where do they come from?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say you're using `pymongo` to work with MongoDB. If that's the case, there is documentation specific to `pymongo` that talks about the `distinct()` method for getting data from a collection, and I'd suggest you start there. (if it's *not* pymongo, then please do tell us what it is).

Comment: my bad. i'm using pymongo with MongoDB. i thought the keyword related to python but now you tell me it related to my database, it make a huge sense right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP confirmed, this is a `PyMongo` call to a MongoDB database, which allows for a distinct find, in the form of:

```
db.collection_name.distinct("property_name")
```

This returns all distinct values for a given property in a collection.

Optionally, if you specify a document filter (effectively a `find()` filter) as a second parameter, your query will first be reduced by that filter, then the `distinct` will be applied. For example:

```
list_of_stocks = db.stocks.distinct("symbol", {"exchange": "NASDAQ"})
```

Answer (score -1):

Distinct keyword is used in DB and it is to return record set only with distinct elements for that particular column.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, and commented about it already. But we still don't know definitively *which* database the OP is using (which is why I didn't post as an answer). And the question, as written, is unclear. Also: if it's MongoDB, as I asserted, then the notion of "column" doesn't exist.